# R: understanding bezier curves

Tags: r, splines

```
library(bezier)
## BEZIER CURVES ##
## SPECIFY PARAMETRIC VALUES FROM 0 TO 1 FOR SAMLPING A BEZIER CURVE
t <- seq(0, 1, length=100)

## BEZIER CONTROL POINTS
p <- matrix(c(0,0,0, 1,4,3, 2,2,0, 3,0,2, 5,5,0), nrow=5, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

bezier_points <- bezier(t=t, p=p[1:3, 1:2])

plot(bezier_points, type = "l")

> p[1:3, 1:2]
[,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    4
[3,]    2    2
```

I am looking at an example in R, and I am confused as to what the second row in my control point matrix `p` represents. `0 0` dictates where my curve begins, and `2 2` where it ends. However, what's an intuitive interpretation of `1 4`? I would like to use these curves for smoothing and would like to have a better grasp of these control points.

Comment: https://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/

Comment: Alternatively, https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I am looking at an example in R, and I am confused as to what the second row in my control point matrix p represents. 0 0 dictates where my curve begins, and 2 2 where it ends. However, what's an intuitive interpretation of 1 4?"

Given the time since you asked this, YQC, you've probably found an answer. But I'm going to write one anyway, as it may help other people. A brief answer is this. You've called a quadratic Bézier function, passing it the points 0 0, 1 4, and 2 2. You understand 0 0 and 2 2, but what does 1 4 do? Look at the graph below. In it, 0 0 is labelled **P0**, 1 4 is labelled **P1**, and 2 2 is labelled **P2**. The points other than **P1** make your Bézier curve. **P1** controls the direction it takes. It starts by aiming directly for **P1** from **P0**, and then gradually changes direction, swinging round until right at the end, it's aiming directly for **P1** from **P2**. At its midpoint, it's aiming equally from both, if I can say it that way.

[image: Plot of results from the B function]

Now I've given the executive summary, here are some details.
First, a preliminary. You don't need to call that [`bezier`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bezier/bezier.pdf) function in such a complicated way, subscripting the matrix. I know why you did: it's because the example in the documentation does it that way. But you can simplify.

This is how you called it:

```
t <- seq( 0, 1, length=10 )

p <- matrix( c(0,0,0, 1,4,3, 2,2,0, 3,0,2, 5,5,0)
           , nrow=5
           , ncol=3
           , byrow=TRUE
           )

bezier_points_1 <- bezier(t=t, p=p[1:3, 1:2])
```

And this is the simpler way:

```
p <- matrix( c(0,0, 1,4, 2,2)
           , nrow=3
           , ncol=2
           , byrow=TRUE
           )

bezier_points_2 <- bezier(t=t, p=p)
```

Instead of subscripting the matrix `p`, I've put into it only the points that I need to recreate your example. I did this because I'm going to work with it further, matching it up with the Wikipedia article on these functions. But first, I'll check that the two calls do give the same results:

```
assert_that( are_equal( bezier_points_1, bezier_points_2 ) )
```

See the documentation for package ["assertthat"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertthat/assertthat.pdf) if you want to know what I just did.

So now let's look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves . You said "I am confused as to what the second row in my control point matrix p represents. 0 0 dictates where my curve begins, and 2 2 where it ends. However, what's an intuitive interpretation of 1 4?". This is explained in the section on Quadratic Bézier curves. Stack Exchange don't encourage answering by linking to other sites, because these sites might die before Stack Exchange does. So I'll copy the appropriate chunk of Wikipedia. As an image, unfortunately, because I don't know a quick way to transcribe the formulae into HTML.

[image: Section on Quadratic Bézier curves]

The key clause is this: "from which it can be concluded that the tangents to the curve at **P0** and **P2** intersect at **P1**. As *t* increases from 0 to 1, the curve departs from **P0** in the direction of **P1**, then bends to arrive at **P2** from the direction of **P1**."

To test my understanding, I recreated the Wikipedia definition in R. Wikipedia describes a function **B** which takes points **P0**, **P1** and **P2**, and a parameter *t*. Here's my translation of Wikipedia's definition into R. In it, **P0**, **P1** and **P2** have to remain the same for all calls that generate a particular curve, while *t* varies.

```
B <- function( t, P0, P1, P2 ) 
{
  (1 - t) * ( (1 - t)*P0 + t*P1 ) +
  t       * ( (1 - t)*P1 + t*P2 ) 
}
```

Now I'm going to test this and see whether it gives the same results as my calls to `bezier` above. If it doesn't, I've not understood it. Here's my code:

```
bezier_points_3 <- matrix( rep(0,20), nrow=10, ncol=2 ) 

P0 <- c(0,0)
P1 <- c(1,4)
P2 <- c(2,2)

for ( i in 1:10 ) {
  ti <- t[ i ]
  bezier_points_3[ i, ] <- B( ti, P0, P1, P2 ) 
}

assert_that( are_equal( bezier_points_3, bezier_points_2 ) )
```

In this, `bezier_points_3` is a matrix that will hold the results. Unlike with `bezier`, I have to call `B` one point at a time, hence the loop. `ti` varies over *t*. **P0**, **P1** and **P2** are your points. The `assert_that` checks that the result is the same as that given by `bezier`.

When I ran this, it did indeed generate the same result as the calls to `bezier`, so I knew that I'd understood the purpose of Wikipedia's **B**. I then tried plotting a graph to answer your question about what **P1** does. The graph is below, and shows the results produced by `B`, as well as point **P1**. Note that, as you said, **P0** is where the curve begins and **P2** where it ends. But **P1** is not on the curve:

[image: Plot of results from the B function]

Again, I'll quote Wikipedia: "the tangents to the curve at **P0** and **P2** intersect at **P1**. As *t* increases from 0 to 1, the curve departs from **P0** in the direction of **P1**, then bends to arrive at **P2** from the direction of **P1**." And that's exactly what's happening. The first line segment, leading out of **P0**, is pointing almost-but-not-quite at **P1**. But then the curve starts bending around. The final line segment, leading into **P2**, is pointing almost-but-not-quite from **P1** to **P2**.

Please note that although I plotted the results from my Wikipedia-inspired function `B`, I'd have got exactly the same plot had I called `bezier`.

Finally, my plotting code is below:

```
colnames( bezier_points_3 ) <- c( "x", "y" )

data <- as_tibble( bezier_points_3 ) 

data_with_P1 <- bind_rows( data, tibble( x=P1[1], y=P1[2] ) )

labels <- tribble( ~x, ~y, ~label 
                 , P0[1], P0[2], "P0"
                 , P1[1], P1[2], "P1"
                 , P2[1], P2[2], "P2"
                 )

data_line_1 <- tibble( x=c(P0[1],P1[1]), y=c(P0[1],P1[2]) )

data_line_2 <- tibble( x=c(P1[1],P2[1]), y=c(P1[2],P2[2]) )

ggplot( data=data, aes(x,y) ) +
  geom_point( data=data_with_P1, size=2 ) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel( mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,label=label), data=labels ) +
  geom_line( data=data_line_1, linetype="dashed" ) +
  geom_line( data=data_line_2, linetype="dashed" )
```

This uses functions from Hadley Wickham's [Tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) system. One of the packages called is [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/), which I find more versatile than base-R plotting. Its graphs also look nicer. I also use ["tibbles"](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html), which are data frames but again more versatile, and more efficient.

Most of the plotting code is just chopping around data and associating it with text or graphics. The first line sets the names in the matrix of results from `B` so that the first column is called "x" and the second "y". The second line generates a tibble (i.e. data frame) from those results. The third line generates another with **P1** added. This will be used for plotting the *points* on my plot, whereas the other will be used for plotting the *lines* between them.

`labels` becomes yet another tibble, holding the coordinates and names of **P0**, **P1** and **P2** in order to label them.

`data_line_1` and `data_line_2` are the dashed lines to **P1**.

And in the plotting code, `geom_point` adds the points including **P1**; the first `geom_line` adds the lines between them; `geom_text_repel` adds the three labels, pushing them away from other stuff they might overlap; and the final two `geom_lines` add the dashed lines. It's a feature of ggplot, designed in from the beginning, that you can build up graphs in layers like this.

If you combine the code fragments above, they'll run, but you need some libraries at the beginning. These are:

```
library( bezier )
library( assertthat )
library( tidyverse )
library( ggplot2 )
library( ggrepel )
```